# Azure DevOps - We could not find a subscription assigned to this user

Tags: azure, devops

i'm new on this Azure DevOps plataform. We have buy 5 of this type od licensing "VSPro 2019 SNGL OLP NL". but I can't get the license assigned to a co-worker to be reflected as an account with "Access Level": Visual Studio Subscription in the company's Azure Devops. Was I wrong to purchase those licenses? Should I have purchased the licenses "VSProSubMSDN ALNG LicSAPk OLP NL Qlfd" ? Is there a way to activate a BASIC access level in our Azure DevOps with the licenses we purchase?

Thanks for your advice!